# Red-blue coloring of the complete graph $K_n$​ such that there are more red edges than blue edges, and there is no red triangle.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

Let us prove that for every $n>1$ there exists a $2$-coloring of a complete graph $K_n$ red and blue, where there are more red edges than blue and there is no monochromatic red triangle, where all the edges are red.

I thought of the pigeonhole principle, because a triangle is basically a $K_3$

For $K_5$ there exists, for less than $5$ it is trivial.
I tried making cycles, and using these circles to make the coloring.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you construct an example for some non-trivial but still small enough $n$ (like $n = 5, 6$)? $\quad$ What's  a good way to guarantee that there are no monochromatic red triangles (or even a larger class of graphs)?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Note, you are not talking about a 2-coloring, but about a 2-**edge** coloring.

Comment: What about my answer do you not get? I'm happy to help. There's no need to put the question on bounty...

Answer (score 6):

A slight re-translation of the question asks that you find a class of graphs with $ >\binom{n}{2}/2 = \frac{n(n-1)}{4}$ edges with no triangles. Hint: what is the maximal number of edges in a triangle-free graph and what are the extremal examples? If you are coming in without any knowledge of extremal graph theory, this theorem is called Mantel's theorem.